# Rundeck login refused to send data

Tags: rundeck

I installed the welcome-project-community-main, following the official instructions:

(running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS Release 20.04)

download the latest release

-> `unzip`

-> `docker-compose build`

-> `docker-compose up -d` (I executed the docker commands in the unzipped folder which contains client, docker-compose.yml, node-demo, README.md, runbooks, rundeck)

-> `docker logs -f rundeck`

-> after the logs stopped flying by i switched to Chrome

-> :4440

-> the login page loaded but after entering the standard logins (admin / admin), it keeps loading forever and in the browser console I got the error:
Refused to send form data to 'http://10.2.4.77:4440/j_security_check' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self'"

In Firefox I get other errors:

-before entering the logins:
XML processing error: Syntax error Address: :4440/user/login Line no. 1, column 1:

-after entering the logins:
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free" style:normal weight:900 stretch:100 src index:1): status=2152398850 source: :4440/assets/static/fonts/fa-solid-900-c500da19d776384ba69573ae6fe274e7.woff2

- tried installing the previous release
- wanted to change the CSP, but it seems like welcome project does not have the rundeck-config.properties
- tried to edit docker-compose.yml by adding `RUNDECK_SECURITY_CONTENTSECURITYPOLICY=form-action 'self' [<IP of my PC>]` but no matter how I change it, when I try to rebuild with docker-compose build, I get an error
- tried to set the env var to `RUNDECK_SERVER_FORWARDED=true` but get error when building

edit: also: the client docker container keeps stopping (and formatting)

Comment: That environment was designed to test it locally (I have tested on firefox), so, try using http://localhost:4440 URL, if you need to set a specific URL, change the RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL env var like RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL: http://my_custom_url_or_ip:4440, (if you're testing that behind a proxy server, maybe this is a better scenario: https://alexkaouris.medium.com/rundeck-with-docker-compose-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy-and-ssl-termination-939fe41b0031)

Comment: that makes sense, I tried to do what you said. But: sorry if that's a stupid question, but when you say to change the env var. Do you mean to add the RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL:ip:4440 to the docker-compose.yml file? If not, could you tell me where else?

Comment: No worries isn't a stupid question :-) yes, but the format should be `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL: http://your_ip:4440`, let me add the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Turned out there was indeed a proxy in place that I did not know of and I ended up skipping the welcome project and installed the normal version on a fresh vm and got it running (which caused me some headaches as well, but it's my 2nd week and I'm still learning and you tip helped me a lot).

Answer (score 0):

That environment was designed to test it locally (I have tested it on Firefox), so, try using the `http://localhost:4440` URL, if you need to set a specific URL, change the `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL` env var (on the `docker-compose.yml` file) like `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL: http://my_custom_url_or_ip:4440`, (if you're testing that behind a proxy server, [this approach](https://alexkaouris.medium.com/rundeck-with-docker-compose-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy-and-ssl-termination-939fe41b0031) is a better scenario).